# What is the difference between date and date()

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

On Node.js, when I execute the following two statements:

```
console.log(new Date);
console.log(new Date());
```

Both produce the same result.

What is the difference?

I have been told to use new Date(), although no reason was given.

Comment: Nothing, but leaving off the `()` may be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the syntax of [*new operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> new constructor[([arguments])]

the parentheses is optional, so both expressions are valid.

```
console.log(new Date);
console.log(new Date());
```

Comment: Note that MDN is not an authority, ECMA-262 is ([*§12.3.3*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-new-operator) applies). That symbology is an invention of the article's author, it is not used in the language specification.